# iphone in app purchases non renewable product buy multiple times

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an In-App Purchase product that is non-renewable. 
When somebody buys this product some content is unlocked for one month (there is nothing to be downloaded or installed).

After one month the user is asked to buy again the non-renewable product, i.e: the user need to buy that non renewable product a second time.

The problem is that when he try to do it the (testing) user got the following message:

```
You've already purchased this but is hasn't been downloaded.
Tap ok to download it now.
```

But my product do not need to be downloaded, and the transaction done before was successfully finished and removed from the transaction queue:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: Please check in iTunes Connect if your In-App Purchase product type is a non-consumable item. Non-consumable items can be purchased only once, so you need a subscription item type.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, the product type is "non-renewing product" and itunes connect says that this kink of product can be bought more than once. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the Non-Renewing Subscription right?

Than make sure what ever the flag you are setting to true to know whether you have purchased that product or not. And also make sure to expire that flag with expiration of that subscription.

And If you are doing so than while buying upon that product again you will probably get this kinda alert...

[image: Subscription alert]